# Access to variable in controller and render

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have on my form template `new.html.twig` a select where all the elements of an entity are loaded (`$categories`).

**Controller**

```
public function newAction(Request $request){

    $entity = new Playlist();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $categories = $em->getRepository('PublicartelAppBundle:Category')->getAllCategories();**

    return $this->render('PublicartelAppBundle:Playlist:new.html.twig', array(
        'categories'  => $categories,
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'form'        => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Select filter that serves to make a search.

Select in my twig template that displays all categories obtained from the query.

**new.html.twig**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="publicartel_appbundle_category_name">Search for category: </label>
    <select id='selectCategory' class="form-control select2">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <option>
                {{ category.name }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

JS in my twig template that detects changes in select option to make a new query and retrieve records from the selected option.

**JS code**

```
$('#selectCategory').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelect = $(this).val();
    $.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, 
    function (filterContent) {
        for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
            for (var name in filterContent.category_result[content]) {
                var result = filterContent.category_result[content][name];
                console.log(result);

                $('#playlist_content_name').append('<option>' + result + '</option>');
            }
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

The result of the new query is done in the `playlist_category` route is assigned to another select this in my twig template with the append method.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="publicartel_appbundle_area_name">Content</label>
    {{ form_widget(form.items.vars.prototype.content, { 'id': 'playlist_content_name', 'full_name': '', required: false, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control select2'}}) }}
</div>
```

This select load other options, but the other select is used to filter options to prevent all options be loaded.

**My problem is that when I try to send the form with any of the options obtained from the search, I get an error that the variable `categories` does not exist in my template twig `new.html.twig`**.

Then, as the method createAction, also conducts a rendering of the template `new.html.twig` also add the variable $ categories there.

**Controller**

```
public function createAction(Request $request){
    $entity = new Playlist();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('playlist_show', array(
            'id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    $categories = $em->getRepository('PublicartelAppBundle:Category')->getAllCategories();

    return $this->render('PublicartelAppBundle:Playlist:new.html.twig', array(
        'categories'  => $categories,
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

But when complete the form, having chosen an option of select which return the search, instead of addressing the `playlist_show` route, directs me to the path `/create` with the form `new.html.twig`.

Comment: So your form->isValid() seems to return false when submitting the result. Have you tried checking what is the reason for this?

Comment: Can't you add the exception you get ?

Comment: I dont see exception in console or anywhere else. Only directs me back to form with the route /create .
How I could see this causing the problem?

Comment: Try with this setting to see what is redirecting: `# app/config/config_dev.yml
web_profiler:
    intercept_redirects: true`  check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/dev_environment.html

Comment: Check the tool you mentioned but I still see exceptions in console.